# Vue html2pdf: How to improve background image quality

Tags: vue.js, pdf

In my vue app, I'm using [vue html 2 pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf) to create downloadable pdf's. My problem is that the generated pdf background image is kinda blurry.

Despite digging into the package documentation and other related posts, I can't manage to get it fixed. Does anyone can think of a solution for this one?

My Vue Js component code:

```
<vue-html2pdf
  :show-layout="false"
  :float-layout="true"
  :enable-download="true"
  :preview-modal="true"
  :paginate-elements-by-height="1400"
  filename="flavourmap"
  :pdf-quality="2"
  :manual-pagination="true"
  pdf-format="A4"
  :pdf-orientation="orientation"
  pdf-content-width="100%"
  :image="{ type: 'jpg', quality: 1 }"
  @progress="onProgress($event)"
  @startPagination="hasStartedGeneration()"
  @hasDownloaded="hasDownloaded($event)"
  ref="html2Pdf"
>
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace 'jpg' with 'jpeg'? I know they are the same, but according to the docs, the image quality is only used for the default 'jpeg' default type string: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0#image-type-and-quality . Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I have tried them all, none of them seem to work. I have the same result with 'png' and also changing 'jpeg' doesn't have any effect. I think it has something to do with the automatic compression. I'm searching for a way to change it into 300dpi, but the documentation is not entirely clear on that. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Ok, problem solved! Seems to only be working with real img-tags, and not background images.

Comment: @Pieter: Yes it works with real img tags only.